# How to move from one directory to another and delete only '.html' files in python?

Tags: python

I attended an interview and they asked me to write a script to move from one directory to another and delete only the `.html` files.
Now I tried to do this at first using `os.remove()` . Following is the code:

```
def rm_files():
    import os
    from os import path
    folder='J:\\Test\\'
    for files in os.listdir(folder):
        file_path=path.join(folder,files)
        os.remove(file_path)
```

The problem I am facing here is that I cannot figure out how to delete only `.html` files in my directory

Then I tried using glob. Following is the code:

```
def rm_files1():
    import os
    import glob
    files=glob.glob('J:\\Test\\*.html')
    for f in files:
        os.remove(f)
```

Using `glob` I can delete the `.html` files but still I cannot figure out how to implement the logic of moving from one directory to another.

And along with that can someone please help me figure out how to delete a specific file type using `os.remove()` ?

Thank you.

Comment: Please don't spam the Python tag. You probably don't need Python-3.x **and** python2.7.

Answer (score 2):

Either of these methods should work.  For the first way, you could just `string.endswith(suffix)` like so:

```
def rm_files():
    import os
    from os import path
    folder='J:\\Test\\'
    for files in os.listdir(folder):
        file_path=path.join(folder,files)
        if file_path.endswith(".html"):
            os.remove(file_path)
```

Or if you prefer `glob`, moving directories is fairly straightforward: `os.chdir(path)` like this:

```
def rm_files1():
    import os
    os.chdir('J:\\Test')
    import glob
    files=glob.glob('J:\\Test\\*.html')
    for f in files:
        os.remove(f)
```

Though it seems unnecessary since `glob` is taking an absolute path anyway.

Answer (score 2):

Your problem can be described in the following steps.

- **move to specific directory**. This can be done using `os.chdir()`
- **grab list of all *.html files**. Use `glob.glob('*.html')`
- **remove the files**. use `os.remove()`

Putting it all together:

```
import os
import glob
import sys

def remove_html_files(path_name):

    # move to desired path, if it exists
    if os.path.exists(path_name):
       os.chdir(path_name)
    else:
       print('invalid path')
       sys.exit(1)

    # grab list of all html files in current directory
    file_list = glob.glob('*.html')

    #delete files
    for f in file_list:
        os.remove(f)

    #output messaage
    print('deleted '+ str(len(file_list))+' files in folder' + path_name)


# call the function
remove_html_files(path_name)
```

Answer (score 1):

To remove all `html` files in a directory with `os.remove()` you can do like this using `endswith()` function

```
import sys
import os
from os import listdir

directory = "J:\\Test\\"
test = os.listdir( directory )

for item in test:
    if item.endswith(".html"):
        os.remove( os.path.join( directory, item ) )
```